# If Annotation is an interface then how it can extend an Object class?

Tags: java, annotations

We define an annotation as an interface as below

```
@interface annot_name {

}
```

and we know that all annotations extends interface `java.lang.annotation.Annotation` by default.

When I checked the java library for `Annotation` interface I found that it was overridding many methods of Object class like `hashCode()` etc.

If Annotation is an interface then how could it extend an Object class and override its methods? Interfaces can only extends other interfaces and not classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> So my question is if Annotation is an interface then how could it
>   extends an Object class and override its methods

Not exactly. [The Java Language Specification §9.2 says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2)

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, **then the interface
>   implicitly declares a `public abstract` member method `m` with signature
>   `s`, return type `r`, and `throws` clause `t` corresponding to each `public`
>   instance method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and `throws` clause `t`
>   declared in `Object`, unless a method with the same signature, same
>   return type, and a compatible `throws` clause is explicitly declared by
>   the interface.**

So any `interface` gets those methods.

For `Annotation`, the designers just chose to re-declare them in the source code so they could document their behavior.