# What is the purpose of Annotation interface?

Tags: java, annotations

Every annotation type implicitly inherits the java.lang.annotation.Annotation interface.

```
package java.lang.annotation;
public interface Annotation{
  boolean equals(Object obj);
  int hashCode();
  String toString();
  Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType();
}
```

But an annotation does not inherit any elements from the Annotation interface, which is an implicit ancestor of all annotation types. So, if I do below, will result in compile time error

```
@CustomAnnotation(toString="toStringValue")
```

Could some one explain me, then

> what is the purpose of Annotation interface? and for what exactly it
>   is used?

Comment: From the [JLS (9.6.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1): "It is a compile-time error if any method declared in an annotation type has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any public or protected method declared in class Object or in the interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation." so maybe that's the purpose of this interface (to enforce that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) is an interface. Those methods are your standard interface `abstract` method declarations.

What you are referring to in your example of

```
@CustomAnnotation(toString="toStringValue")
```

(the use of `toString`) is an [annotation type *element*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1). These are two different things. The latter is a special syntax for annotation types. `Annotation` is not an annotation type, it is an interface type.

What the `Annotation` type provides is a common supertype for annotation types. So you can do

```
Annotation custom = SomeClass.class.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
custom.annotationType();
```

These methods (`equals`, `toString`, and `hashCode`) are simply redefined in the `Annotation` interface to specify their behavior. They are not strictly required since the Java language implicitly [adds all those methods to all interface types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463691/if-annotation-is-an-interface-then-how-it-can-extend-an-object-class/22463773#22463773) if they don't declare them.

Comment: Annotation Type is also a kind of interface with few restrictions, one of its restriction is that no inheritance allowed between annotation types, what's the point of creating a super type then?

Comment: What the Annotation type provides is a common supertype for annotation types, if this is the only purpose, why Annotation is not a marker interface?, I'm confused !!!

Comment: @AmitBhati An annotation type is an interface type, but an interface type is not necessarily an annotation type. It's not a marker interface because the Java language wants to include more behavior (the `annotationType` method) and describe more specific behavior for the other 3 methods.